# Binding TabControl ItemsSource and Headers together

Tags: wpf, xaml, header, tabcontrol

I have a TabControl, which is currently displaying how I want it to, using the following:

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="1" Background="{x:Null}" ItemsSource="{Binding TabPanels}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content.DataContext.BreadcrumbEnd}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Content}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

This shows the correct header on each tab, and the content within. The items source is bound to an ObservableCollection where ContentAreaHolder is as follows:

```
public ContentAreaHolder(UserControl content)
{
    this.Content = content;
}

private UserControl _Content;
public UserControl Content
{
    get
    {
        return _Content;
    }
    set
    {
        _Content = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Content");
    }
}
```

It looks super messy, and totally unnecessary. However, I started off with an ObservableCollection and was unable to get the same effect. I used the slightly altered xaml of:

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="1" Background="{x:Null}" ItemsSource="{Binding TabPanels}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.BreadcrumbEnd}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding .}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

and the content shows correctly, but the header remains blank.

I have tried setting the header through the DisplayMemberPath, without binding but just setting it to `DataContext.BreadcrumbEnd` to no avail.

Why is my header not showing correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You should not add UI elements to a source collection of a view model. `TabPanels` should be an `ObservableCollection<YourType>` instead of a an `ObservableCollection<UserControl>`. `YourType` is the class where the `BreadcrumbEnd` property is defined. You could then to this:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabPanels}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding BreadcrumbEnd}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:UserControl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```